# How prove this $\frac{\cos{x}-\sin{y}}{\sin{x}-\cos{y}}=\frac{1-2\cos{x}}{1-2\sin{x}}$

Tags: trigonometry

let $\dfrac{\pi}{2}<x<\dfrac{3\pi}{2},0<y<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,and such
$$\dfrac{1-\sin{x}}{1-\cos{x}}=\dfrac{1-\sin{y}}{1-\cos{y}}$$
show that
$$\dfrac{\cos{x}-\sin{y}}{\sin{x}-\cos{y}}=\dfrac{1-2\cos{x}}{1-2\sin{x}}$$
my idea:
$$\Longleftrightarrow (\cos{x}-\sin{y})(1-2\sin{x})=(\sin{x}-\cos{y})(1-2\cos{x})$$
But I fell this follow can't solve this problem,Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure that there is at least one sublimer solution than this as this is not how the problem came along , but its legitimate.

If we cross multiply the relation to be proved, we find 
$$\sin x+\sin y-(\cos x+\cos y)=-2\cos(x+y)$$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) & [Double Angle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) Formulas,

$$2\cos\frac{x-y}2\left(\sin\frac{x+y}2-\cos\frac{x+u}2\right)=-2\left(\cos^2\frac{x+u}2-\sin^2\frac{x+u}2\right)$$

Now we can safely cancel $\displaystyle\cos\frac{x+y}2-\sin\frac{x+y}2$ as for  $\displaystyle\cos\frac{x+u}2-\sin\frac{x+y}2=0\implies\tan\frac{x+y}2=1$

$\displaystyle\iff\frac{x+y}2=n\pi+\frac\pi4\iff x+y=2n\pi+\frac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer

But, this is not possible due to the given ranges of $x,y$

So, we need $\displaystyle\cos\frac{x-y}2=\cos\frac{x+y}2+\sin\frac{x+y}2$

$\displaystyle\implies\sin\frac{x+y}2=\cos\frac{x-y}2-\cos\frac{x+y}2$

$\displaystyle\implies\sin\frac x2\cos\frac y2+\cos\frac x2\sin\frac y2=2\sin\frac x2\sin\frac y2$

$\displaystyle\implies\cot\frac x2+\cot\frac y2=2\ \ \ \ (1) $

---

$$\text{Now, }\frac{1-\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1-2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2}{2\sin^2\frac x2}=\frac12\csc^2\frac x2-\cot\frac x2$$

$$=\frac12\left(1+\cot^2\frac x2\right)-\cot\frac x2=\frac{\cot^2\dfrac x2-2\cot\dfrac x2+1}2$$

**Method** $\#1:$

So from the given condition, if we set $$\frac{1-\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1-\sin y}{1-\cos y}=K$$

$\displaystyle\implies\cot\frac x2,\cot\frac y2$ will be roots of

$$\frac{\cot^2\dfrac u2-2\cot\dfrac u2+1}2=K\iff\cot^2\dfrac u2-2\cot\dfrac u2+1-2K=0$$

$\displaystyle\implies\cot\frac x2+\cot\frac y2=\frac21$ which is same as $(1)$

**Method** $\#2:$

So from the given condition, $\displaystyle\frac{\cot^2\dfrac x2-2\cot\dfrac x2+1}2=\frac{\cot^2\dfrac y2-2\cot\dfrac y2+1}2$

$\displaystyle\implies \left(\cot\dfrac x2-\cot\dfrac y2\right)\left(\cot\frac x2+\cot\frac y2-2\right)=0$

If $\displaystyle\cot\dfrac x2-\cot\dfrac y2=0,\tan\frac x2=\tan\frac y2\implies \dfrac x2=\dfrac y2+m\pi\iff x=2m\pi+y$  where $m$ is any integer

But, this is not possible due to the given ranges of $x,y$

Comment: @chinamath, How about this?

Comment: @labbhttacharjee,It's nice! Thank you

Comment: @chinamath, some amelioration & amendment have been incorporated. Btw, is it possible to share the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let us use the duplication formulas

$$
\cos(\theta)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \
\sin(\theta)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \ \text{where} \ t=\tan\big(\frac{\theta}{2}\big)
\tag{1}
$$

We deduce

$$
\frac{1-\sin(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}=
\frac{1-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}=
\frac{(t-1)^2}{2t^2} \tag{2}
$$

Let us then put $t_x=\tan\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)$ and $t_y=\tan\big(\frac{y}{2}\big)$.
Since $\cos(x)<0$ and $\cos(y)>0$, we have $\cos(x)\neq\cos(y)$ and hence
$t_x\neq t_y$. By (2) we have $\frac{(t_x-1)^2}{2t_x^2}=\frac{(t_y-1)^2}{2t_y^2}$,
or in other words

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
0 &=& (t_x-1)^2t_y^2-(t_y-1)^2t_x^2 \\
 &=& \bigg((t_x-1)t_y+(t_y-1)t_x\bigg)\bigg((t_x-1)t_y-(t_y-1)t_x\bigg) \\
 &=& \bigg(2t_xt_y-t_x-t_y\bigg)\bigg(t_y-t_x\bigg) \\
 &=& 2t_xt_y-t_x-t_y \ (\text{because} \ t_x\neq t_y).
\end{array}\tag{3}
$$

Next, expanding $\Delta=(\cos(x)-\sin(y))(1-2\sin(x))-(\sin(x)-\cos(y))(1-2\cos(x))$
we see that

$$
\Delta=
\cos(x)-\sin(x)+\cos(y)-\sin(y)-2\cos(x)\cos(y)+2\sin(x)\sin(y)
$$

Let us put $A=\cos(x)-\sin(x)+\cos(y)-\sin(y)$ and $B=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$.

We have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
A&=& \frac{1-2t_x-t_x^2}{1+t_x^2}+
\frac{1-2t_y-t_y^2}{1+t_y^2} \\
&=& \frac{1-2t_x-t_x^2+t_y^2-2t_xt_y^2-t_x^2t_y^2}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}+
\frac{1-2t_y-t_y^2+t_x^2-2t_yt_x^2-t_x^2t_y^2}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)} \\
&=& \frac{2-2(t_x+t_y)-2t_xt_y(t_x+t_y)-2t_x^2t_y^2}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)} \\
&=& \frac{2-2(t_x+t_y)-(t_x+t_y)^2-\frac{1}{2}(t_x+t_y)^2}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)} \\
&=& \frac{2-2(t_x+t_y)-\frac{3}{2}(t_x+t_y)^2}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)} \\
&=& \frac{2-2(t_x+t_y)-\frac{3}{2}(t_x^2+t_y^2)-\frac{3}{2}(t_x+t_y)}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)} \\
&=& \frac{2-\frac{7}{2}(t_x+t_y)-\frac{3}{2}(t_x^2+t_y^2)}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)} \\
\end{array}
$$

and

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
B&=& \frac{1-t_x^2}{1+t_x^2}\frac{1-t_y^2}{1+t_y^2}
-\frac{2t_x}{1+t_x^2} \frac{2t_y}{1+t_y^2} \\
&=& \frac{1-t_x^2-t_y^2+t_x^2t_y^2}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}
-\frac{2(t_x+t_y)}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}  \\
&=&
\frac{1-t_x^2-t_y^2+\big(\frac{t_x+t_y}{2}\big)^2}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}-
\frac{2(t_x+t_y)}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}  \\
&=& 
\frac{1-\frac{3}{4}\big(t_x^2+t_y^2\big)+\frac{t_xt_y}{2}}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}-
\frac{2(t_x+t_y)}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}  \\
&=& 
\frac{1-\frac{7}{4}\big(t_x+t_y\big)-\frac{3}{4}\big(t_x^2+t_y^2\big)}{(1+t_x^2)(1+t_y^2)}
  \\
\end{array}
$$

We see that $A=2B$, so $\Delta=0$ as wished.